# What is the default proxy behavior for HTTP caches

Tags: http, proxy

We build a server we ship to clients.  We would like the server to work in the presence of intermediate proxies.  We do not want the proxies to cache our requests.

Right now, one of our servlets explicitly disables caching using the following HTTP header:

```
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 17:00:00 MST
```

Our other servlets do not specify any HTTP headers related to caching.  My question is whether or not we should change those other servlets to also specifically disable caching.  In particular, what do proxy servers do when there are no caching headers present?

Comment: Are you saying that your server serves up everything with caching turned off? even for static resources like images, CSS & JavaScript files? This seems like a really bad idea for performance! (you don't need to cache the reports, but the static stuff should cache for sure!)

Comment: The server doesn't have any static content.  It's serves XML/JSON to remote clients.  For example, a backend weather server that only serves up weather information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) If you don't supply caching hints (like Cache-Control: no-cache -- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-21.html#cache-response-directive.no-cache), proxies can cache heuristically.

(b) The date in the Expires header field example is invalid: it might not have any effect.